# How to remove section number from subsection labels?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I need to make all my subsection labels look like the following:

> 1. Section title
>      A. Subsection title 1
>      B. Subsection title 2

Instead of

> 1. Section title
>      1.A. Subsection title 1
>      1.B. Subsection title 2

Answer (score 5):

It should suffice to include the following in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
```

The default includes the prefix `\thesection.`, so I've just removed it.

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{A subsection}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

The numbering seems like it may be confusing as it includes duplication.

---

Adding the dot after the section titles should probably be done in two places - the ToC *and* and the section heading. The following two additional redefinitions in your preamble should cover this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1.\hfil}}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}% Update section number displays
\makeatother
```

The `\numberline` redefinition adds a dot after every entry in the ToC, while `\@seccntformat` adds the dot when printing the section title.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1.\hfil}}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}% Update section number displays
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{A subsection}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```